# Driver Power State Failure BSOD Laptop Windows 10

Tags: laptop, bsod

For the last few months my laptop has been suffering from frequent BSOD reported to be driver power state failures. I've not identified any pattern in my activities when these occur so I'm at a bit of a loss with regards to how to tackle the issue. I think they've started since I upgraded to windows 10.

Edit - real dump file added

[dump file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/majopepvldy0ym4/MEMORY.DMP?dl=0)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Install **WinDbg** and analyze **C:\WINDOWS\Minidump\091816-5296-01.dmp** or upload **C:\WINDOWS\Minidump\091816-5296-01.dmp** this file to dropbox or something else and share the link

Comment: this txt file is useless crap. share the real dmp

Comment: I've uploaded the proper file

Answer (score 0):

[Looking at the dmp with Windbg](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks), shows that the crash is caused by the nVIDIA GPU driver for your NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980M (`PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_13D7`):

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, A device object has been blocking an Irp for too long a time
Arg2: ffffe0018b1b6060, Physical Device Object of the stack
Arg3: ffffd001b8079990, nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER on Win7 and higher, otherwise the Functional Device Object of the stack
Arg4: ffffe0018f906ca0, The blocked IRP

Debugging Details:
------------------

Implicit thread is now ffffe001`8b6b5800
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for nvlddmkm.sys

DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 401

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  10586.589.amd64fre.th2_release.160906-1759

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  Notebook                        

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  P17SM-A                        

SYSTEM_SKU:  Not Applicable                  

SYSTEM_VERSION:  Not Applicable                  

BIOS_VENDOR:  American Megatrends Inc.

BIOS_VERSION:  4.6.5

BIOS_DATE:  03/27/2014

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  Notebook                        

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  P17SM-A                        

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  Not Applicable                  

DUMP_TYPE:  1

BUGCHECK_P1: 3

BUGCHECK_P2: ffffe0018b1b6060

BUGCHECK_P3: ffffd001b8079990

BUGCHECK_P4: ffffe0018f906ca0

DRVPOWERSTATE_SUBCODE:  3

FAULTING_THREAD:  8b6b5800

CPU_COUNT: 8

CPU_MHZ: aea

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 3c

CPU_STEPPING: 3

CPU_MICROCODE: 6,3c,3,0 (F,M,S,R)  SIG: 1E'00000000 (cache) 1E'00000000 (init)

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x9F

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.14321.1024 amd64fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff801f875784a to fffff801f87cf406

STACK_TEXT:  
00 nt!KiSwapContext
01 nt!KiSwapThread
02 nt!KiCommitThreadWait
03 nt!KeWaitForSingleObject
04 dxgkrnl!DpiFdoHandleDevicePower
05 dxgkrnl!DpiDispatchPower
06 nvlddmkm
07 nvlddmkm
08 nt!PopIrpWorker
09 nt!PspSystemThreadStartup
0a nt!KiStartSystemThread

STACK_COMMAND:  .thread 0xffffe0018b6b5800 ; kb

BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.10586.589.amd64fre.th2_release.160906-1759

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x9f_3_dxgkrnl!dpifdohandledevicepower

2: kd> !irp ffffe0018f906ca0
Irp is active with 6 stacks 4 is current (= 0xffffe0018f906e48)
 No Mdl: No System Buffer: Thread 00000000:  Irp stack trace.  
     cmd  flg cl Device   File     Completion-Context
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>[IRP_MJ_POWER(16), IRP_MN_SET_POWER(2)]
            0 e1 ffffe0018b1b6060 00000000 fffff800140ed6c0-ffffd00028bea8e0 Success Error Cancel pending
           \Driver\pci  dxgkrnl!DpiFdoPowerCompletionRoutine
            Args: 00000000 00000001 00000001 00000000
 [IRP_MJ_POWER(16), IRP_MN_SET_POWER(2)]
            0 e1 ffffe0018f740040 00000000 fffff801f8798438-ffffe00191b84230 Success Error Cancel pending
           \Driver\nvlddmkm nt!PopRequestCompletion
            Args: 00000000 00000001 00000001 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-ffffe00191b84230    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
2: kd> !podev ffffe0018b1b6060
Device object is for:
  DriverObject 8b172670
Current Irp 00000000 RefCount 0 Type 00000023 AttachedDev ffffe0018b1b55a0 DevFlags 00001040
Device queue is not busy.
Device Object Extension: ffffe0018b1b67b0:
PowerFlags: 00000040 =>SystemState=0 DeviceState=4
Dope: 00000000:
2: kd> !devstack ffffe0018b1b55a0
  !DevObj           !DrvObj            !DevExt           ObjectName
  ffffe0018f740040  \Driver\nvlddmkm   ffffe0018f740190  
> ffffe0018b1b55a0  \Driver\ACPI       ffffe0018b166ab0  
  ffffe0018b1b6060  \Driver\pci        ffffe0018b1b61b0  NTPNP_PCI0016
!DevNode ffffe0018b1b51d0 :
  DeviceInst is "PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_13D7&SUBSYS_74811558&REV_A1\4&d70769b&0&0008"
  ServiceName is "nvlddmkm"
```

Try the [latest driver 372.90 from nVIDIAs homepage](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/107566/en-us).

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a go but I'll be surprised if it works. I keep that driver up to date.

Comment: Apologies for coming back to you late on this. I've ensured that my laptop is now running the most up to date Nvidia drivers but the BSOD is still happening occasionally. As I've said before there doesn't seem to be any particular activity that causes it but it only ever seems to happen within a few minutes of my booting the laptop up.

Comment: I don't have a PC right now so I can't look at new dumps.